# Open external webpages within sharepoint

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, public-website, user-experience, integrated-mode

How can i open external websites within Sharepoint. Such that the experience seems seamless to the user and they don't get to know for the site open is not on sharepoint.

I guess the option is embedding the external websites in frames.

Please enlighten my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add Page Viewer Web Part that hold external URL site and show it as I Frame.

Edit SharePoint Page > Add Web Part > try to search for Page Viewer Web Part > Edit it > Add your site URL

Comment: I`ve tried with Page Viewer, the problem it open in iFRAME and has a scroll bar based on the size of the page. Now based on the dynamic content of the page the height may reduce or increase. Thus looking for an option that doesn't gives the scroll bar. I tried to convince the business users, but they want a smooth seamless flow. Any other suggestions?